# From a programming point-of-view, what are the biggest challenges that the Stackoverflow team deals with?

Tags: discussion, technology, stack-exchange-history

I'm interested in learning what might be the challenges that the SO team has the most trouble with. I know *alot* goes into keeping SO up & running.  My guess is that concurrency issues are big, .. but what about dealing with the huge bandwidth issues?

Comment: "huge bandwidth issues" fat pipes are common in data centres these days. Getting on board with a large fibre transit company isn't hard (though very costly..). That coupled with load balanced servers,  connections, and DNS, it all becomes pretty robust and (usually) little maintenance (though setting it all up initially and tweaking is, well, "fun"..)